# Excel, how to delete certain range values in excel table, if possible delete them from the table list

Tags: excel

My excel table contains only numbers from negative to positive values.

I only want the table remain with certain number and above (threshold) and delete all other values.

How to execute in excel or by using its VB (Alt+F11).

Its a huge table of numbers, like 4000 x 4000 range of x,y

Please advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uy1_nOkj648

Comment: It won't be 4000 x 4000 once it's done.  Do you have a problem if the table is no longer square?